# Projecting a point cloud onto the camera plane based on the projection matrix

Tags: python, camera-calibration, point-clouds, lidar

I have a point cloud which I convert from .dat to .ply using open3d. The contents of the .ply file is an (nx3) matrix corresponding to the x, y, z points, as well as another (nx3) that corresponds to the RGB information. The total number of points are well over 2 million (the lidar was mounted on top of a vehicle). I also have a set of stereo cameras the were mounted along side the LiDAR (one left, one right), of which I only have the camera intrinsic parameters.

I am trying to replicate a formula found in several papers, which can be seen [here](https://home.isr.uc.pt/~cpremebida/files_cp/Road%20Detection%20Using%20High%20Resolution%20LIDAR.pdf), equations 2 & 3. It is originally found in the [Kitti dataset](http://www.cvlibs.net/publications/Geiger2013IJRR.pdf) paper, equation 8. Basically, they are projecting a point cloud based on the cameras projection with the following equation: [where P is the projection matrix--containing the camera intrinsic parameters, R the rectifying rotation matrix of the reference camera, T_{cam}^{velo} the rigid boy transformation from lidar coordinates to camera coordinates, and T_{velo}^{imu}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEBRQ.png)

I want to note that not all papers used the last parameter (T_{velo}^{imu}), and because I don't have the imu information I will omit that parameter.

While I only have the camera intrinsic parameters, I am able to extract the camera rotation and translation by way of the [Essential matrix](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_epipolar_geometry/py_epipolar_geometry.html). Along with the data, I also have a file containing the yaw, pitch and roll (in degrees) of the camera and lidar at the time that the images where being taken. I know that I can extract a rotation matrix from these parameters, but I am not quite sure how to use them in this case, specifically to obtain the rigid body transformation from lidar to camera coordinates. I should also mention that I have the real world coordinates of the camera at the time each image was being taken (in x, y ,z coordinates).

Comment: To get the Lidar points in camera coordinates frame, you just need the pose (position + orientation) of the lidar with respect to the camera. You said you have the orientation of the lidar and the camera (I suppose these orientation are relative to the world coordinate system). Do you also have their positions ?

Comment: @Liumatt I have the real world coordinates of each (x, y, z), as well as a yaw, pitch, and roll for both cameras and Lidar at the time the images are taken. From the yaw, pitch, and roll I can calculate a [rotation matrix](http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node102.html), but no translation vector. My understanding is that I need a relative rotation and translation between Lidar and camera, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you need the relative rotation and translation between le lidar and the camera. If you have the position and orientation of each sensor in the world coordinates system, you can easily find the relative ones. I will detail it in an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the detailed answer to transform points between the lidar and the camera coordinates systems. I used the homogeneous representation of 3D transformations (4x4 matrices) because it is easier to manipulate, but it would be exactly the same if you used R and T instead. (the equation would just be longer)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. By pose, I only have the xyz coordinates, so just a vector and not a matrix. Or do you mean the orientation I get from the yaw pitch and roll (which is a 3x3 matrix).

Comment: By pose I mean orientation and position which can be represented as a 4x4 matrix when using homogeneous coordinates (see the "1" that was added after x, y, z of the lidar point in equation (1)). This 4x4 matrix has a simple form: its upper-left part is R (the rotation matrix 3x3), the last column is t (the position) and its last row is [0 0 0 1]. Homogeneous coordinates are just a simpler way to apply rigid transformation. (You could also use: R X + t instead = P X)

Comment: I see. I understand. I will go ahead and implement this. Thank you for your help. Much appreciated, cheers.